# Discrepancy between time and datetime modules for measuring code runtime

Tags: python, datetime, duration

I am measuring the response time on a function using the time module. The time module is supposed to output seconds as a float, so I am saving a start time value (time.clock()) and taking another reading at the end, and using the difference as a runtime. While watching the results, we noted the runtimes seemed high -- something that seemed to take less than 2 seconds, was printing as 3-and-change, for instance. Based on the perceived issue, I decided to double-check the results using the datetime module. Printing the two side-by-side shows the time module values are almost double the datetime values.

Anyone know why that might be?

Here is my code:

```
for datum in data:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    startts = time.clock()
    check = test_func(datum)
    runtime = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    runts = time.clock() - startts
    print(check, "Time required:", runtime, "or", runts)
```

Some of my results:

```
XYZ Time required: 0:00:01.985303 or 3.7836029999999994
XYZ Time required: 0:00:01.476289 or 3.3465039999999817
XYZ Time required: 0:00:01.454407 or 3.7140109999999993
XYZ Time required: 0:00:01.550416 or 3.860824000000008
```

I am assuming this sort of issue would have been noticed before, and I am just missing something basic in my implementation. Can someone clue me in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue. The test_func I am testing is using a multi-threaded process. I both did not know that, and did not know it was an issue.

The time module uses processor time (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/time.html), while the datetime module uses wall clock time (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html). Using the difference in the datetime timestamps told me how much actual time had elapsed, and for our purposes was the relevant information.

I hope this helps someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like time.clock() has been Deprecated since version 3.3

Maybe [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock) will help ?

> time.clock()
>   On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.
>
> Deprecated since version 3.3: The behaviour of this function depends
>   on the platform: use perf_counter() or process_time() instead,
>   depending on your requirements, to have a well defined behaviour.

Comment: True but this doesn't explain the source of the discrepancy.